# How to add work item (User Story) to a previous Iteration (Sprint)

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Trying to backfill a Sprint that has already passed.  Is there a way to move my newly created User Story to a previous Iteration (Sprint)?
I ask because I only see that I'm allowed to move work items to current and next iterations, but that won't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just update Iteration on the work item form:

[image]

To change many work items, use [Bulk modify work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/bulk-modify-work-items?view=azure-devops#edit-one-or-more-fields)

Comment: Was hoping I could drag multiple work items over, but can do this too. Thx buddy.

Comment: @Modifier, you can do this. Here is the instruction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/bulk-modify-work-items?view=azure-devops#edit-one-or-more-fields